# How to minify JS file using Webpack similar to Angular 2 ng build

Tags: angular, webpack, gzip

When I used ng build on a angular-cli environment, the size of the  JS bundle files came down from 2.8MB to 400Kb.

I have a non angular project where the module bundling is performed using webpack. I tried using webpack -p, but there's not much reduction in size as it was done by angular ng build.

I have already used DedupePlugin and UgligyPlugin in webpack config

Can someone tell me what's happening inside ng build and how to achieve the same using webpack?

Is there a way to achieve gzip compression similar to ngbuild?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing AOT build in both the cli and your webpack environment?  AOT will make a big difference.

Also, check out the Webpack config in the Angular2 Webpack Starterkit. https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter   I've used it and achieved similar results between the cli and webpack.